# Kendo UI Scheduler overflow-y not scrolling

Tags: css, kendo-ui, overflow, kendo-scheduler

I've got a Kendo UI Scheduler which i created for a web application that needs to support mobile devices. I've set the mobile configuration property to true. When viewed in a mobile device, the scheduler will overflow the screen on the y axis.

[image]

However scrolling will not go beyond the middle of the scheduler control:

[image]

I've set overflow-y to auto, like so:

```
.k-scheduler-mobile {
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

And I've tried with every other possibility for the overflow-y property.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Has anyone found a solution to this?